# Should column-number-mode count glyphs instead of bytes?

Tags: unicode, column

I noticed today that `column-number-mode` seems to count bytes in the underlying character encoding, or something similar, instead of user-visible glyphs. For example, on this line:

```
foo ☕ bar
```

...when point is on ☕, it reports column 4, but when point is on the space after ☕, it reports 6.

Is this expected? I know counting glyphs can be surprisingly difficult, and can have tricky dependencies, at least if you try to get it 100% correct, but even just the common cases like this would be a good start, even if it didn't handle eg combinations. Is there any Emacs history specifically around this that I should know? Or should I go ahead and report a bug/feature request?

Comment: I suggest you report it as an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The Emacs developers will consider it.

Comment: I think that the relevant Emacs history is that originally Emacs used ASCII, there were no fonts (except whatever the terminal gave you), no Unicode and no multibyte. Since then, certain things have been added to `current_column()` (in `src/indent.c`), notably invisibly characters due to text properties or overlays (those can throw off the column calculation by large amounts), but certainly not multibyte AFAICT.  And the calculation is approximate: the first conditional in the function says: `/* Avoid becoming abysmally slow for very long lines.  */` and `/* this is an approximation! */`.

Comment: Note also that the second conditional says: `/* If the buffer has overlays, text properties,
     or multibyte characters, use a more general algorithm.  */` and it calls `current_column_1()` to do the calculation, but AFAICT, that function does not handle multibyte - or it handles it incorrectly perhaps. I'm not sure.

Comment: It's counting correctly: ☕ U+2615 is a 'double-width' character, just compare it what happens if you use ☖ U+2616 instead.